Check if Drawing Objects Intersects in AutoCAD
I have multiple lines (Layer Name = Checkline) that runs thru Polylines (Layer Name = 0_String).
If the line intersects 3 polylines, those 3 polylines are added to a selection set, and the layer name for them are changed to 0_3 String.
So intersected count per line equals Layer name.....
1 Intersect = 0_1 String, 2 Intersects = 0_2 String,....and so on.
All layers are already in the drawings, I just need to assign them.
Picture 1 Before Code is run - Pink line are the checkline, white plines are 0_String
Picture 2 After code is run, it should look like this - Because checkline on far right only intersect with 1 polyline, the layer changes to 0_1 String, the 4th row of polylines from right, the checkline intersects 2 polylines, so Layername changes to 0_2 String
If intLine.IntersectWith(StringPLine, acExtendNone) <> "" I get an error here, I'm not sure how to check if intersect happend or not (Error Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch)
Sub addLayers()

Dim intLine As AcadEntity
Dim StringPLine As AcadEntity

Dim acSelSet As AcadSelectionSet
Dim selObject As AcadEntity

' Loop through each line in the drawing
For Each intLine In ThisDrawing.ModelSpace

    ' Create a new selection set
    Set acSelSet = CreateSelectionSet("sset", ThisDrawing)

    ' Check if it is a line on the polylines
    If intLine.Layer = "0_Checkline" Then

        ' Loop through all polylines and check if it intersects
        For Each StringPLine In ThisDrawing.ModelSpace

            ' Check if the correct polylines are used
            If StringPLine.Layer = "0_String" Then

                ' Check if the line intersects with the polyline
                If intLine.IntersectWith(StringPLine, acExtendNone) <> "" Then
                    ' Add to the selection set
                    acSelSet.AddItems StringPLine
                End If

            End If
        Next

        ' Loop through each object in the selection set
        For Each selObject In acSelSet
            ' Change the layer name of the object
            selObject.Layer = "0_" & acSelSet.Count & "String"
        Next

    End If
    acSelSet.Delete
Next
End Sub

I have updated my code and removes the selection set, as there is no real need for it. The only problem I have is checking if the intPoints var is empty. If VarType(intPoints) <> vbEmpty Then , it does not seem to pick up that intPoints are empty.
As per this Image From left the layer should be 0_1 String, 0_2 String, 0_3 String per row, but it counts all 5 polylines so it uses 0_5 String Layer
EDIT: I changed If VarType(intPoints) <> vbEmpty Then to If Ubound(intPoints) <> -1 Then as the Ubound val seems to be -1 when it does not intersect. Code is Working Perfect now .
Sub addLayers()

Dim intLine As AcadEntity
Dim intPoints As Variant
Dim entPoly As AcadEntity
Dim acadOb(0 To 7) As AcadEntity

Dim i As Long
i = 0

Dim k As Long

'///Looping thru each line in drawing
For Each intLine In ThisDrawing.ModelSpace

    'Checks if it is a Line on the polylines
    If intLine.Layer = "0_Checkline" Then

        '///Looping thru all polylines and checking if it intersects with
        For Each entPoly In ThisDrawing.ModelSpace
            'check if correct polylines are used
            If entPoly.Layer = "0_String" Then
                'Check if Line intersects polyline
                intPoints = intLine.IntersectWith(entPoly, acExtendNone)
                    If UBound(intPoints) <> -1 Then
                        
                      'add object to array
                       Set acadOb(i) = entPoly
                       i = i + 1
                         
                    Else
                         MsgBox ("Var Empty")
                    End If
                    
            End If
        Next
       
        For k = 0 To 7
        On Error Resume Next
        acadOb(k).Layer = "0_" & i & " String"
       
        Next
       
        'Reset I if new Inline is searched
        i = 0
        Erase acadOb()
    End If
  
Next

End Sub


Per the documentation, the IntersectWith method returns a variant (of doubles, each representing a coordinate value), not a string. As such, you'll need to check whether the variant is empty.
An example of how to do this is included in the documentation linked above.

That helped clear the error Thanks. I do however get a new error on acSelSet.Additem StringPline (Invalid argument pSelSet in Additems) I will do a bit of research on why I'm getting this

Similar issue - the argument should be a variant; you're passing it an object - see documentation for the method here

I've updated my code in my question. Everything is working fine except for the most important part that needs to check if variant is empty, I know for sure it must be empty as the lines do not intersect.

Did you consult the example in the documentation for IntersectWith?

I changed If VarType(intPoints) <> vbEmpty Then to If Ubound(intPoints) <> -1 Then as the Ubound val seems to be -1 when it does not intersect. Using vbEmpty didn't work as there is values inside the array even when it doesn't intersect. It is strange. But my code works now.

My current code takes extremely long to run, if you look at it, can you maybe advise how I can make it run quicker.? There is a lot of entities so I'm guessing that is why it is taking so long

Since you have a nested for loop instead your outer for loop which is also iterating over all modelspace entities, your code is performing a number of iterations equal to the square of the number of entities in modelspace, which could be a huge number. Instead, you should obtain two selection sets, one of lines, one of polylines, and then check for intersections between each polyline and line.

Would you be able to provide a sample code for me? I'm struggling with selection sets.
I am busy looking at it, but not getting anywhere

I could write the code, but that's not what StackOverflow is about - have a go at writing the code using the hints I've provided and, if you get stuck, post a question and we'll steer you in the right direction.
